# HTTP login API authentication by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

```
function login1() {

  var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var url = "http://agero-dev.apigee.net/v1/id/auth/login";
  var http = getHTTPObject(); 
  if (http.status == 200 ) {
  this.http.open("post", url, false, user, pass);
  this.http.send("");
    document.location = job-list.html;
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect username and/or password!");
  }
  return false;
}

function getHTTPObject() {
  var xmlhttp = false;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {                      // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  return xmlhttp;

}
```

Please look at the above code, while giving wrong username and password, it showing an alert, but while using correct login, it doesnt redirecting to job-list.html page, please advice?

Comment: you code is wrong on so many levels i suggest you have a look at basic Ajax tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started ,especially on how to handle serve's reponse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use readyState to check whether response is ready.

```
http.onreadystatechange=function() {

  if (http.status == 200 && http.readyState == 4) {
        .... //your code
        window.location = job-list.html;
  }

}       

http.open("post", url + '?user=' + user + '&pass=' + pass, true);
http.send();
```